# Energy of a signal $s(t)=\int_{-4}^{3} e^{{\pi}{i}{t}{u}} du$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to calculate the energy of a signal: $s(t)=\int_{-4}^{3} e^{{\pi}{i}{t}{u}} du$. I know the energy can be calculated from $<s,s>=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (s(t)*\overline{s(t)})dt$. The formula for $s$ gives $s=\frac{1}{{i}{\pi}{t}}(e^{3{\pi}it}-e^{-4{\pi}it})$ From this the energy $E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{{\pi}^2{t^2}}(2-e^{{\pi}it7}-e^{-{\pi}it7}) dt$. This is far as i can get.

Comment: Using $$\int_\mathbb R\frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^2}dt=\pi\,|a|$$ and correcting some typos, one gets $$E=\int_\mathbb R\frac2{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(7\pi t)}{t^2}dt=2\cdot7$$ More generally, for $$s_{a,b}(t)=\int_a^be^{\pi itu}du$$ one gets $$E_{a,b}=2\cdot(b-a)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea (perhaps with complex integration, but perhaps you already know it):

$$2-e^{7\pi i t}-e^{-7\pi it}=-\left(e^{\frac72\pi it}-e^{-\frac72\pi it}\right)^2=4\sin^2\frac72\pi t\implies$$

$$\frac4{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2\frac72\pi t}{t^2}=\frac4{\pi^2}\frac{7\pi^2}2=14$$